# Is CPUQuota per core or per machine?

Tags: firefox, systemd, resource-usage, flatpak, cgroup

In order to prevent buggy sites from freezing my system I imposed a CPU Quota limit of 95%, a Memory High of 2G and a Memory Max of 3G on my Firefox flatpak as described by the [flatpak documentation](https://docs.flatpak.org/en/latest/tips-and-tricks.html).

```
$ cat .config/systemd/user/app-flatpak-org.mozilla.firefox-.scope.d/override.conf 
[Scope]
CPUQuota=95%
MemoryHigh=2G
MemoryMax=3G
```

However after applying the changes I noticed that the browser became rather laggy. Reading again the systemd resource control documentation, it seems to be somewhat ambiguous over how CPUQuota is applied, namely, it says that

> The percentage specifies how much CPU time the unit shall get at maximum, relative to the total CPU time available on one CPU

I don't understand if the "total CPU time available on one CPU" is the CPU time of a single core, or the total CPU time of all (usually one) system processors. And if it is the former, then why would Firefox start lagging?

Note that Firefox's `about:memory` reports only 800MB~ of used memory at the root process, so I am tempted to discard the memory limits as the cause.